# Huffy model number

Tags: mountain-bike

I need to find the model number in order to get help from Huffy.

I think it is somewhere in this sticker.

Is the model number here?

[image: Close-up of the underside of the down tube at the bottom bracket, showing a white sticker with "56321 24021 A" in large print followed by contact information for Huffy Corp.]

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but if you give them the serial number (stamped onto the bottom bracket shell, partly visible in the bottom LH corner of your photo) they may be able to work out the model (and more) themselves. Obviously it's possible you've tried that already.

Comment: It's not very likely that anybody here is going to be able to answer your question based on this photo alone. There aren't really any standards around _any_ numbering scheme in the bicycle industry. _Maybe_ if you could tell us when the bike was made someone could answer. Even that might be a long shot. Your best bet is probably to call the number on the sticker and ask them to help you find the model number. Alternatively, you could ask us for help with whatever you're going to ask Huffy about. There's a good chance we could help you with that. :) (unless, of course, it's a warranty issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your bike?
If so, 65321 is the model number
Web search for "huffy 65321"
Huffy's website search returns the same result for 65321. The site returns several results results for 24021 - so if this isn't your bike maybe one of those is.

[image]
It a Huffy Scout in denim blue
[image]

These bikes usually come from the factory with all bearings too tight.
Check both hubs, the bottom bracket and the headset before riding.